# Data Scraping: Webpage doesn't exist unless I load it through the main website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from multiple webpages using BeautifulSoup. Each of these webpages has the same format with a code at the end that uniquely identifies them, for eg. `www.sample_000.com`. The problem is that if I randomly select a code 123 and try and scrape `www.sample_123.com`, I get nothing since the page doesn't exist. I get a HTTP 404 error if I try and open it from a browser directly. However, if I go to the main website and select the appropriate input values to open `www.sample_123.com`, it loads just fine.

After loading it once from the main website, I can now scrape it and open it in the browser independently without going through the main website. What is going on here and how can I scrape these webpages without opening them first through the main website?

Update: I tried to use Selenium to load each webpage using the respective inputs before scraping it. It works now but it's incredibly slow. Would really appreciate if someone if recommend a faster method.

Comment: have you tried using selenium with a chromedriver?

Comment: @qbbq is that the only way to get around this? I've never used selenium but seems tedious. I have to scrape thousands of these webpages, each with a different code.

Comment: others may have a more elegant way, but I have used selenium quite a bit and like the way it handles scripting on pages (which sounds like what your website is using). its not that tedious once you get it going. to open the website, you can use the following code: `chrome_path = r"path_to_chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
driver.maximize_window()

link = "www.test.com/blah"

driver.get(link)` without knowing more of your website, I don't know the options you need (pagination, clicking a link etc). IMHO selenium handles scripting well.

Comment: I'll test it out, thanks!

Comment: do you mind sharing the url ?

Comment: thats ok, no problem

Comment: you might be able to use request sessions to send and initial request, and then use that session to get the sequential other sites.

Comment: @qbbq Here's the link: https://mnregaweb2.nic.in/netnrega/loginframegp.aspx?page=C&state_code=17

So I was able to use Selenium to select from all the four drop down menus. However, each time I run this, FIrefox/Chrome is launched and I need to run it thousands of time and then scrape the data. How do you think I can do that without blowing up my laptop?

Comment: OK I've had a look at the website, not sure what you want to scrape, but it's doable, also check if you have permission to scrape from the site, I'm not sure what the content is and how deep you want it to go. My way would be to generate a list of urls after you do your 4 selections and open those sequentially after the urls are in a list.

Comment: What exactly do you want to scrape? I see that the state_code parameter in the URL is dynamic, but what do you want to scrape from each page?

Comment: @LuckyZakary I want to scrape the data from every possible combination of the 3 input parameters (District, Block, Panchayat) (financial year doesn't matter). I want the whole table so I'm doing ```table = bs.find_all('table')[3]``` after clicking Proceed.

Comment: @LuckyZakary https://mnregaweb2.nic.in/netnrega/writereaddata/state_out/jobcardreg_1719004041_local.html is an example of one of the output pages. The problem is that this link only opens AFTER I load it by inputing the parameters above in the main website. I can't scrape it directly by using the 1719004041 code.

Comment: @IAA_ just as a matter of interest, I was able to open the link directly with the code I gave you. just a matter of what you want now from the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you get https://mnregaweb2.nic.in/netnrega/writereaddata/state_out/jobcardreg_1719004041_local.html, **scraping** is easy with `requests` or `scrapy` any other web request packages.
But getting the list of urls from the main website is a bit tricky. The main website https://mnregaweb2.nic.in/netnrega/loginframegp.aspx?page=C&state_code=17
is actually ran with a database. Each time you select an option, you are actually posting an http request to the server. Then the server returns a response which is further interpreted by the javascript engine on your browser. Thus why you cannot simply **scrape** the html as the url of `_local.html` are in fact not present in the main window. you have to render them one by one by clicking the proceed button.

If the number of sub-websites is limited, I would suggest just collect the list manually. If you only consider automation, use selenium but do expect to spend considerable time testing and debugging.

Answer (score 1):

try this code, just change the location of your chromedriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

chrome_path = r"path_to_chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
driver.maximize_window()

link = "https://mnregaweb2.nic.in/netnrega/writereaddata/state_out/jobcardreg_1719004041_local.html"

driver.get(link)
```